# Delete empty lines and trim surrounding spaces in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

This command removes empty lines:

```
sed -e '/^$/d' file
```

But, how do I remove spaces from beginning and end of each non-empty line?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d' file.txt

`s/^ *//`  => left trim
`s/ *$//`  => right trim
`/^$/d`    => remove empty line
```

Comment: `sed -r 's/^\s*//; s/\s*$//; /^$/d'`

Comment: `sed -r "/^\s*\$/d ; s@^\s*(.*)\s*\$@\1@"` - less `sed`-"calling" :)

Comment: Note to OS X users: the equivalent answer is `sed -E 's/^ +//; s/ +$//; /^$/d' file.txt` (the equivalent to the generalized, `\s`-based variant is: `sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//; s/[[:space:]]+$//; /^$/d' file.txt`. (There is no `-r` option for `sed` on OS X (as of 10.8); `-E` turns on extended regular expressions, which support `[[:..:]]`-style character classes, but apparently not their shorthand equivalents such as `\s`.)

Comment: This can be slightly improved with the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414410/delete-empty-lines-using-sed/24957725#24957725

Comment: rather than space it might be better to use [[:blank:]] which includes also tabs

Answer (score 9):

Even more simple method using awk.

```
awk 'NF { $1=$1; print }' file
```

`NF` selects non-blank lines, and `$1=$1` trims leading and trailing spaces (with the side effect of squeezing sequences of spaces in the middle of the line).

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
sed -r 's/^\s*(.*\S)*\s*$/\1/;/^$/d' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar, but using `ex` editor:

```
ex -s +"g/^$/de" +"%s/^\s\+//e" +"%s/\s\+$//e" -cwq foo.txt
```

For multiple files:

```
ex -s +'bufdo!g/^$/de' +'bufdo!%s/^\s\+//e' +'bufdo!%s/\s\+$//e' -cxa *.txt
```

To replace recursively, you can use [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (e.g. `**/*.txt`).